# jQuery sort custom table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I'm working on a small userscript to sort a table, the structure of the table is really weird however. What i'm trying to do is to add an extra sort feature so I can sort on the ranking (#) of the persons.

Table data looks like this:

```
<table id="outer">
    <tr>
        <td><div id="bgn"></div></td>
        <td><a href="#">User 1</a></td>
        <td>
            <table id="inner">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rank</td>
                        <td id="tdp">#28</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- more rows -->
</table>
```

There are some additional `<td>`'s but they are not important right now. There are about 52 rows, but these could vary, of course.

Current jQuery code I have:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    var rankings = [];

    $(document).on('click', '#tdr', function() {
    // skipping first line because it's the header

    $('tr:not(:first-child').each(function () {
        var rank = $(this).find('#tdp').text();
        var rank2 = rank.substring(1, rank.length)
        rankings.push(rank2);
    });

        console.log(rankings.sort(sortNumber));
    });

    function sortNumber(num1, num2) {
        return num1 - num2;
    }
});
```

### [JS Bin Example](http://jsbin.com/diranipi/7/edit)

The output in the console is a correctly sorted array with all the rankings, I just don't have any idea how to also swap the corresponding `<tr>`'s so that the table get's rebuild the right way. Looking for any tips or pointers!

Comment: did you try this: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: That HTML looks invalid, the href attribute is not closed and it looks like you're using the same ID multiple times, and ID's are unique. Start with valid HTML, and things get easier. Also, `sort` works directly on a jQuery collection, no need to push to an array, but you have append the table back in the DOM in the right order to see any changes.

Comment: While it is possible to solve your issue by iterating through all `<TR>` DOM elements and actually moving them within the `<TABLE>` element, it is a bad idea. Moving a DOM element means that first you remove it from the DOM and insert it at some other place later. [Have a look at jQuery manipulation commands](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).

DOM manipulation is a very expensive operation and you actually don't need to see the intermediate states on your page. As both John and adeneo mentioned, there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion is not really into "sorting" the rows, but re-constructing the table with the sorted rows. But this should do the job:

```
rankings = rankings.sort(sortNumber);
var table = $('<table></table>');
for (var i = 0; i < rankings.length; i++) {
  var row = $('tr').filter(function() {
    var rank = $(this).find('#tdp').text();
    return rank.substring(1, rank.length) == i;
  });
  table.append(row);
}
$('#originalTable').html(table.html());
```